# App getting too much load while selecting images from Gallary

Tags: android, android-studio, bitmap, imageview, base64

I am developing app in which I have to choose images from device gallary one by one. User can select as much images as they want from Gallary one after another.

Its ok when User selects only 1 or 2 images from Gallary. But, **The issue is** app getting too much load when user selects more than 3 images.
It also taking load while i am entering characters to my EditText.

Here, I am converting images to Base64 as below to post it to the server :

```
 public void JsonArray() {
    if (arrayListImages != null) {
        jsonItemArray = new JSONArray();

        JSONObject jsonObjItemImages = null;
        JSONArray jsonArrayItemImages = null;

        String strBase64_ItemImage1 = "";
        String strBase64_ItemImage2 = "";
        String strBase64_ItemImage3 = "";
        String strBase64_ItemImage4 = "";

        for (int i = 0; i < arrayListImages.size(); i++) {
            JSONObject jObj = new JSONObject();

                if (arrayListImages.get(i).getStrItemImagePath1() != null) {
                    strBase64_ItemImage1 = Common.convertToBase64(arrayListImages.get(i).getStrItemImagePath1());
                }
                if (arrayListImages.get(i).getStrItemImagePath2() != null) {
                    strBase64_ItemImage2 = Common.convertToBase64(arrayListImages.get(i).getStrItemImagePath2());
                }
                if (arrayListImages.get(i).getStrItemImagePath3() != null) {
                    strBase64_ItemImage3 = Common.convertToBase64(arrayListImages.get(i).getStrItemImagePath3());
                }
                if (arrayListImages.get(i).getStrItemImagePath4() != null) {
                    strBase64_ItemImage4 = Common.convertToBase64(arrayListImages.get(i).getStrItemImagePath4());
                }

                jsonObjItemImages = new JSONObject();
                jsonArrayItemImages = new JSONArray();

                if (strBase64_ItemImage1 != null) {
                    JSONObject jsonObjectImage1 = new JSONObject();
                    jsonObjectImage1.put("name", strBase64_ItemImage1);
                    jsonArrayItemImages.put(jsonObjectImage1);
                    strBase64_ItemImage1 = null;
                }
                if (strBase64_ItemImage2 != null) {
                    JSONObject jsonObjectImage2 = new JSONObject();
                    jsonObjectImage2.put("name", strBase64_ItemImage2);
                    jsonArrayItemImages.put(jsonObjectImage2);
                    strBase64_ItemImage2 = null;
                }
                if (strBase64_ItemImage3 != null) {
                    JSONObject jsonObjectImage3 = new JSONObject();
                    jsonObjectImage3.put("name", strBase64_ItemImage3);
                    jsonArrayItemImages.put(jsonObjectImage3);
                    strBase64_ItemImage3 = null;
                }
                if (strBase64_ItemImage4 != null) {
                    JSONObject jsonObjectImage4 = new JSONObject();
                    jsonObjectImage4.put("name", strBase64_ItemImage4);
                    jsonArrayItemImages.put(jsonObjectImage4);
                    strBase64_ItemImage4 = null;
                }

            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            try {
                if (jsonArrayItemImages != null) {
                    jsonObjItemImages.put("images", jsonArrayItemImages);
                    if (jsonObjItemImages != null) {
                        jObj.put("photo", jsonObjItemImages);
                    }
                }
            } catch (JSONException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            jsonItemArray.put(jObj);
        }
    }
```

Function to select image from Gallary is as Below :

```
private void onSelectFromGalleryResult(Intent data) {
    Uri selectedImage = data.getData();
    String[] filePath = {MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA};
    Cursor c = myActivity.getContentResolver().query(selectedImage, filePath, null, null, null);
    c.moveToFirst();

    int columnIndex = c.getColumnIndex(filePath[0]);
    String picturePath = c.getString(columnIndex);
    c.close();
    switch (flagImage) {

        case 1:
            fileImagePath1 = new File(picturePath);
            selectImageView(0, fileImagePath1, 1);
            break;

        case 2:
            fileImagePath2 = new File(picturePath);
            selectImageView(0, fileImagePath2, 2);
            break;

        case 3:
            fileImagePath3 = new File(picturePath);
            selectImageView(0, fileImagePath3, 3);
            break;

        case 4:
            fileImagePath4 = new File(picturePath);
            selectImageView(0, fileImagePath4, 4);
            break;

    }
}
```

Below is the function to convert image to Base64 :

```
public static String convertToBase64(String path) {
    String encodedImage4 = "";
    try {
        BitmapFactory.Options bmOptions = new BitmapFactory.Options();
        ByteArrayOutputStream baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
        Bitmap bitmap = decodeSampledBitmapFromResource(path, 200, 200);
        bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 100, baos);
        byte[] byteArrayImage = baos.toByteArray();
        encodedImage4 = Base64.encodeToString(byteArrayImage, Base64.DEFAULT);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return encodedImage4;
}
```

Now, any one tell me that HOW WE CAN LOAD IMAGES in IMAGEVIEW in best and efficient way ?

or

Is there anything in my code to improve ?
I will be thankful for your suggestion.

Thanks.

Comment: Don;t pass around images this way. Pass a file path and open the file instead.

Comment: Use light weight library for gallery like https://android-arsenal.com/details/1/4395

Comment: Resize image and then take base64 String and bytes

Comment: @Qamar Sir, User can select only one image at a time.

Comment: That library is configurable.

Comment: GalleryConfig config = new GalleryConfig.Build()
                        .limitPickPhoto(1)
                        .singlePhoto(true)

Comment: In This way, private void galleryIntent() {
        Intent intent = new Intent(
                Intent.ACTION_PICK,
                MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI);
        startActivityForResult(intent, SELECT_FILE);

    }

Comment: Sir, Its giving me error as below : java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Failed to allocate a 11315274 byte allocation with 6270128 free bytes and 5MB until OOM

Answer (score 0):

To load faster, one options is to use

```
GalleryConfig config = new GalleryConfig.Build()
                        .limitPickPhoto(1)
                        .singlePhoto(true)
                        .hintOfPick("Select image")
                        .filterMimeTypes(new String[]{"image/jpeg"})
                        .build();
GalleryActivity.openActivity(MainActivity.this, reqCode, config);
```

Check [TelegramGallery](https://android-arsenal.com/details/1/4395) for further implementation

Answer (score 0):

I got the Solution as below :

I was loading images before as below way :

```
Picasso.with(getActivity()).load(fileImagePath1).into(imgviewItemImageHouseHoldDialog1);
```

But, Now I have added `.resize(400,400).onlyScaleDown()` as below :

```
Picasso.with(getActivity()).load(fileImagePath1).resize(400,400).onlyScaleDown().into(imgviewItemImageHouseHoldDialog1);
```

Here, It will resize image with 400 * 400 and `onlyScaleDown()` will resize image if its larger than 400*400 size.

DONE.

But, its giving me below error at last :

```
java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Failed to allocate a 11315274 byte allocation with 6270128 free bytes and 5MB until OOM
```